# Cart redirection Prestashop Non-Ajax

Tags: ajax, url, redirect, prestashop, cart

I'm trying to redirect my cart.

Basically when the user is on the detailed view of product page and clicks on "add to cart" the item is added to cart and I choose to stay on the same page. However I'd now like them to go to a custom page I made where I host a custom module. I'm using the Non-Ajax version of the cart and can't seem to do it. Any tips or indications?

I have already tried using the hook actionCartSave which works fine with the Ajax version of the cart.

I wouldn't mind showing some code but I have no idea what part would be of any help.

Comment: Show us some code, what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying ::redirect lines in cart.php works just fine.